# How to add a foreign key to a table programmatically?

Tags: database, install, setup-script, programmatically, foreign-key

I am trying to add a set of new tables and I'm trying to add a foreign key to link these tables. I have looked online to try and find some information about `addForeignKey()` but cannot find anything.

Looking at `Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::addForeignKey()` and `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::getFkName()` I thought I had got below setup correctly

```
->addForeignKey(
     $installer->getFkName('namespace_module/shop', 'area_id', 'namespace_module/area','area_id'),
     $installer->getTable('namespace_module/shop'), 
     'area_id',
     $installer->getTable('namespace_module/area'), 
     'area_id',
     Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, 
     Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
)
```

But the exception says different

```
Zend_Db_Exception Object
(
[_previous:Zend_Exception:private] => 
[message:protected] => Undefined column "shop_locator_shop"
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 0
[file:protected] => /Users/myname/Sites/site/www/lib/Varien/Db/Ddl/Table.php
[line:protected] => 450
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /Users/myname/Sites/site/www/app/code/local/Namespace/Module/sql/namespace_module_setup/install-0.1.0.php
                [line] => 110
                [function] => addForeignKey
                [class] => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => FK_SHOP_LOCATOR_SHOP_AREA_ID_SHOP_LOCATOR_AREA_AREA_ID
                        [1] => shop_locator_shop
                        [2] => area_id
                        [3] => shop_locator_area
                        [4] => area_id
                        [5] => CASCADE
                        [6] => CASCADE
                    )

            )
```

Basically how do I go about adding a foreign key to my table (I have added a screen shot of what I am trying to achieve)

[image: database]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
->addForeignKey(
     $installer->getFkName('namespace_module/shop', 'area_id', 'namespace_module/area','area_id'),
     'area_id',
     $installer->getTable('namespace_module/area'), 
     'area_id',
     Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, 
     Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
)
```

The difference in my code is that I removed the first line below `getFkName`.
since you are calling `addForeignKey` on a table while creating it, you don't need to specify it's name again.

as a general rule use:

```
->addForeignKey(
     $installer->getFkName('TABLE ALIAS', 'FK_FIELD', 'REF_TABLE_ALIAS','REF_TABLE_FIELD'),
     'CURRENT_TABLE_FIELD_NAME',
     $installer->getTable('REF_TABLE_ALIAS'), 
     'REF_TABLE_FIELD',
     Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, 
     Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
)
```

**[Edit]**
You should be looking at `Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::addForeignKey` because you are using it on an instance of `Varien_Db_Ddl_Table`.